# How to have two SKSpriteNodes always have the same position?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have two SKSpriteNodes that I would like to keep the same position. newLeftObject, and newLeftObjectBackground. What is the best way to make it so that the two objects always keep the same position even when force is applied to them. I tried setting their mass and density equal to each other but they still end up having slightly different positions while falling. Thank you, any help is appreciated!

```
func createNewObjectLeftAndMoveToCenter() {

    colorBackground.removeFromParent()
    blackBackground.removeFromParent()

    var newLeftObject = SKSpriteNode()
    var newRightObject = SKSpriteNode()

    var newLeftObjectBackground = SKSpriteNode()
    var newRightObjectBackground = SKSpriteNode()


    var distance = sqrt(((colorBackground.size.width / -2) - (verticalTarget.position.x)) * ((colorBackground.size.width / -2) - (verticalTarget.position.x)))

    var distanceToCenter = sqrt(((0 - (verticalTarget.position.x))) * (0 - (verticalTarget.position.x)))



    newLeftObject.size = CGSize(width: distance, height: colorBackground.size.height)
    newLeftObject.position = CGPoint(x: verticalTarget.position.x - (newLeftObject.size.width / 2), y: colorBackground.position.y)
    newLeftObject.color = colorBackground.color
    newLeftObject.zPosition = 30
    addChild(newLeftObject)

    newLeftObjectBackground.size = CGSize(width: distance + 14, height: blackBackground.size.height)
    newLeftObjectBackground.position = CGPoint(x: verticalTarget.position.x - (newLeftObject.size.width / 2), y: colorBackground.position.y)
    newLeftObjectBackground.color = UIColor.black
    newLeftObjectBackground.zPosition = 20

    addChild(newLeftObjectBackground)

    newRightObject.size = CGSize(width: distanceToCenter + colorBackground.size.width / 2, height: colorBackground.size.height)
    newRightObject.position = CGPoint(x: verticalTarget.position.x + (newRightObject.size.width / 2), y: colorBackground.position.y)
    newRightObject.color = colorBackground.color
    newRightObject.zPosition = 40
    addChild(newRightObject)

    newRightObjectBackground.size = CGSize(width: (distanceToCenter + colorBackground.size.width / 2) + 14, height: blackBackground.size.height)
    newRightObjectBackground.position = CGPoint(x: verticalTarget.position.x + (newRightObject.size.width / 2), y: colorBackground.position.y)
    newRightObjectBackground.color = blackBackground.color
    newRightObjectBackground.zPosition = 35
    addChild(newRightObjectBackground)

    newLeftObject.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: newLeftObject.size)
    newLeftObject.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    newLeftObject.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    newLeftObject.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
    newLeftObject.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    newLeftObject.physicsBody?.density = 1
    newLeftObject.physicsBody?.mass = 1
    newLeftObject.physicsBody?.applyAngularImpulse(1)

    newLeftObject.physicsBody?.applyForce(CGVector(dx: -10000, dy: 10000))

    newLeftObjectBackground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: newLeftObjectBackground.size)
    newLeftObjectBackground.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    newLeftObjectBackground.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    newLeftObjectBackground.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    newLeftObjectBackground.physicsBody?.density = 1
    newLeftObjectBackground.physicsBody?.mass = 1
    newLeftObjectBackground.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
    newLeftObjectBackground.physicsBody?.applyAngularImpulse(1)

    newLeftObjectBackground.physicsBody?.applyForce(CGVector(dx: -10000, dy: 10000))

    newLeftObject.position = newLeftObjectBackground.position

    var moveNewObjectToCenter = SKAction.moveTo(x: 0, duration: 0.25)

    newRightObject.run(moveNewObjectToCenter)
    newRightObjectBackground.run(moveNewObjectToCenter)

    colorBackground = newRightObject
    blackBackground = newRightObjectBackground

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make one a child of the other using addChild()

Comment: Shortest answer I've seen in a whiel :) +1